# c#/core close application but allow a child process to continue running

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm trying to handle events triggered by a MTA.

The MTA calls the following code/exe. It doesn't proceed until the `exe` exits.

I need the MTA to proceed (exe to exit), whilst the code in `Process` is still running.

I'm assuming that when I create the task, since it's a child process the main context completing terminates the child context.

I've also tried creating its as a new thread along with other methods.

Please could someone explain how I would achieve this?

```
namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task.Run(() => new Foo().Process(args));
        }
    }

    class Foo
    {
        public async void Process(string[] args)
        {
            // do something
            await Task.delay(200);
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why exactly you want to end the application and keep something running? If you end the process all the threads of the process will be killed. Why not keep the application alive until the processing finishes?

Comment: I would love to, unfortuantly the MTA only proceeds when the EXE exits. I need the MTA to proceed whilst still processing the data. Its far from ideal but I'm sure there must be a way to achieve this.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by *MTA*?

Comment: sorry its a mail transfer agent. I'm trying to intercept an event raised by it. I can pickup the inital request but it hangs processing it fully until my exe is terminated

Comment: There is no way to close your application and keep a thread running. Your only chance is to start another process (using `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start`).

Comment: If I was on Linux I would just kick the script off with nohup. But I’m on windows. I’ve tried launching it from a bash script and calling start “” along with other methods to no avail.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma  sounds great I will give it a go. Thank you

Comment: @FedericoDipuma `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` still waits on the process started to complete :(

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is an `async` Main method this is now supported in .NET Core. This way you can await the processing and the process will stay open until the processing is finished.

Here is your sample changed to this approach. I increased the wait time to 5 seconds so it is more visible.

```
namespace ConsoleApp4
{
   class Program
   {
      static async Task Main(string[] args)
      {
         await new Foo().Process(args);
      }

      class Foo
      {
         public async Task Process(string[] args)
         {
            // do something
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            // do something
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer AlesD, unforunatly the console app still stays open whils the `Foo` is running

Comment: Yes that is the point if you close it it will stop it from running. How do you expect a process thread to run after the main process closes? What do you run inside Foo?.

Comment: I was wondering if it could be achieved. Thanks for clarifying. I'm going to write another exe that will call `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` and pass the parameters to it.

Comment: Yes probably then this is the best solution.